# SQL for Where DATE >= DATE +90 days and END DATE is empty

Tags: sql, date

`END DATE` is a different field in a different table.
`DATE` format is `DateFull`.

I have attempted using `DATEADD` and `getdate()` without success.

I'm a novice at SQL, help is appreciated.

Cathie

Comment: what flavor of SQL are you using? Oracle, MySQL, MS-SQL, something else?

Comment: Let's see your attempt

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE date >= DATEADD(day, 90, GETDATE()) AND end_date IS NULL
```